# Error al crear función para sumar valores de array

Tags: c++, funciones, recursión

Tengo que crear un programa para diseñar una función de nombre sum que, dado un puntero "a" entero que apunta a la primera posición de un array de números enteros y un entero "n" con la longitud del array dado, devuelva la suma de todos sus valores mediante una función recursiva.

A continuación diseñar un programa que lea un número entero n, que representa el número de valores que se leerán a continuación y, a continuación lea n valores que hay que almacenar en un array. Finalmente, muestra por pantalla el resultado de la suma de todos los valores del array.

Ejemplo de Entrada 1

0

Ejemplo de Salida 1

0

Ejemplo de Entrada 2

4 1 2 3 4

Ejemplo de Salida 2

10

No obstante tengo un error:

```
/tmp/program.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/tmp/program.cpp:9:7: error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}' and 'int [n]')
   cin >> a;
   ~~~~^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:168:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(bool&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream] 
       operator>>(bool& __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:168:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'bool&' to an rvalue of type 'bool'
   cin >> a;
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:172:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits] 
       operator>>(short& __n);
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:172:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'short int' [-fpermissive]
   cin >> a;
          ^
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: cannot bind rvalue '(short int)((int*)(& a))' to 'short int&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:175:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream] 
       operator>>(unsigned short& __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:175:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'short unsigned int' [-fpermissive]
   cin >> a;
          ^
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: cannot bind rvalue '(short unsigned int)((int*)(& a))' to 'short unsigned int&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:179:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits] 
       operator>>(int& __n);
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:179:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
   cin >> a;
          ^
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: cannot bind rvalue '(int)((int*)(& a))' to 'int&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:182:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream] 
       operator>>(unsigned int& __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:182:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'unsigned int' [-fpermissive]
   cin >> a;
          ^
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: cannot bind rvalue '(unsigned int)((int*)(& a))' to 'unsigned int&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:186:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream] 
       operator>>(long& __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:186:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'long int' [-fpermissive]
   cin >> a;
          ^
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: cannot bind rvalue '(long int)((int*)(& a))' to 'long int&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:190:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream] 
       operator>>(unsigned long& __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:190:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'long unsigned int' [-fpermissive]
   cin >> a;
          ^
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: cannot bind rvalue '(long unsigned int)((int*)(& a))' to 'long unsigned int&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:195:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream] 
       operator>>(long long& __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:195:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'long long int' [-fpermissive]
   cin >> a;
          ^
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: cannot bind rvalue '(long long int)((int*)(& a))' to 'long long int&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:199:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream] 
       operator>>(unsigned long long& __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:199:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'long long unsigned int' [-fpermissive]
   cin >> a;
          ^
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: cannot bind rvalue '(long long unsigned int)((int*)(& a))' to 'long long unsigned int&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:235:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(void*&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream] 
       operator>>(void*& __p)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:235:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'void*&' to an rvalue of type 'void*'
   cin >> a;
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:120:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream]
       operator>>(__istream_type& (*__pf)(__istream_type&))
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:120:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int [n]' to 'std::basic_istream::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream::__istream_type&) {aka std::basic_istream& (*)(std::basic_istream&)}'
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:124:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios]
       operator>>(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:124:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int [n]' to 'std::basic_istream::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream::__ios_type&) {aka std::basic_ios& (*)(std::basic_ios&)}'
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:131:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream]
       operator>>(ios_base& (*__pf)(ios_base&))
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:131:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int [n]' to 'std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)'
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:214:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(float&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream]
       operator>>(float& __f)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:214:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int [n]' to 'float&'
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:218:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(double&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream]
       operator>>(double& __f)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:218:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int [n]' to 'double&'
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:222:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long double&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream]
       operator>>(long double& __f)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:222:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int [n]' to 'long double&'
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:259:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf]
       operator>>(__streambuf_type* __sb);
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:259:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int [n]' to 'std::basic_istream::__streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf*}'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/string:53:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.tcc:1465:5: note: candidate: template std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.tcc:1465:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: note:   mismatched types 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>' and 'int [n]'
   cin >> a;
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/istream:991:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/istream.tcc:963:5: note: candidate: template std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/istream.tcc:963:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_CharT2' ('char' and 'int')
   cin >> a;
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/istream:991:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/istream.tcc:931:5: note: candidate: template std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT& __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/istream.tcc:931:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_CharT' ('char' and 'int [n]')
   cin >> a;
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:756:5: note: candidate: template std::basic_istream& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream&, unsigned char&)
     operator>>(basic_istream& __in, unsigned char& __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:756:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: note:   cannot convert 'a' (type 'int [n]') to type 'unsigned char&'
   cin >> a;
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:761:5: note: candidate: template std::basic_istream& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream&, signed char&)
     operator>>(basic_istream& __in, signed char& __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:761:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: note:   cannot convert 'a' (type 'int [n]') to type 'signed char&'
   cin >> a;
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:803:5: note: candidate: template std::basic_istream& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream&, unsigned char*)
     operator>>(basic_istream& __in, unsigned char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:803:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: note:   cannot convert 'a' (type 'int [n]') to type 'unsigned char*'
   cin >> a;
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:808:5: note: candidate: template std::basic_istream& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream&, signed char*)
     operator>>(basic_istream& __in, signed char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:808:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: note:   cannot convert 'a' (type 'int [n]') to type 'signed char*'
   cin >> a;
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /tmp/program.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:980:5: note: candidate: template typename std::enable_if >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Istream>, std::__is_extractable::__istream_type, _Tp&&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Tp>::__istream_type>::type std::operator>>(_Istream&&, _Tp&&)
     operator>>(_Istream&& __is, _Tp&& __x)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:980:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/tmp/program.cpp:9:10: note:   variable-sized array type 'int (&)[n]' is not a valid template argument
   cin >> a;
          ^
/tmp/program.cpp:10:17: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
   return sum(a,n);
                 ^
/tmp/program.cpp:4:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int sum(int, int)'
 int sum(int a, int n);
     ^~~
/tmp/program.cpp: In function 'int sum(int, int)':
/tmp/program.cpp:16:28: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
     return sum(a,n-1)+a[n-1];//recursividad
                            ^
**********************************************************************
File "", line 3, in __main__
Failed example:
    printf '0' | ./program
Expected:
    0
Got:
    (127)bash: ./program: No such file or directory
**********************************************************************
File "", line 5, in __main__
Failed example:
    printf '4 1 2 3 4' | ./program
Expected:
    10
Got:
    (127)bash: ./program: No such file or directory
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   2 of   2 in __main__
***Test Failed*** 2 failures.
```

Me gustaría resolver el error manteniendo la estructura del programa.

Mi programa es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int sum(int a, int n);
int main(){
  int n=0;
  int a[n];
  cin >> n;
  cin >> a;
  return sum(a,n);
}
int sum(int a, int n){
  if(n==0){
        return 0;
    } 
    return sum(a,n-1)+a[n-1];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es muy claro: No puedes hacer `cin >> a` cuando `a` está definido como `int a[n]`, es más, tampoco puedes definir `a` como `int a[n]`, porque el compilador espera una expresión constante para `n` y no lo es. Es una variable que no se resuelve en tiempo de compilación, sino en tiempo de ejecución.

Como el enunciado indica, `a` tiene que definirse como un puntero a entero:

```
int * a;
```

Así que tu código quedaría así:

```
int sum(int * a, int n);
int main() {
    int n = 0;
    int * a;
    cin >> n;
    if( n <= 0)
        return 0;

    a = new int[n]; //Reserva dinamica de memoria para n enteros
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i]; //Obtienes cada entero

    cout << sum(a, n) << endl;

    delete[] a; //Elininas la memoria reservada

    return 0;
}

int sum(int* a, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return sum(a, n - 1) + a[n - 1];
}
```